# save current page url to node xml file

Tags: php, xml, nodes, window.location

I have the following code to get current page url.

```
<?php  
    include("../../../includes/header.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="linkwebsite"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("linkwebsite").innerHTML = 
"Page location is: " + window.location.href;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to save the page ERL (id="linkwebsite") in my `values.xml` file in the node `<linkwebsite> </linkwebsite>`.

In my `include.php` file I have loaded the XML file and loaded the child element. I normally use this function on form post, but now I want to save on page load (dynamic URL).

```
if (isset($_POST['submit8'])) {
    $linkwebsite->nodeValue = $_POST['linkwebsitenya'];
    htmlentities($xml->save('values.xml'));
}
```

Comment: You are muddling PHP code (which runs on the server, *before* the page has been sent to the browser) with JS code (which runs on the browser, *after* the page has been sent there from the server). If you want to send data from the browser to the server, you can use AJAX; otherwise, you can find out the URL that was asked for in the PHP itself using values in the the `$_SERVER` array.

Comment: And your question is?